# If a corporate network disables peer-to-peer networking, will that affect web-based proxy services?

Tags: proxy, filtering

I'm under the impression that PHP-based proxies download the content of a site to their server before sending it back to the browser just like browsing any standard website site. Am I correct in saying this?

Note that URL filtering is not the issue here.

Comment: Is the proxy website in question one that you are running?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct- The web proxy will act as a middle man in between you and the content being requested through the proxy. P2P disabled will in no way affect the results of using a web based proxy, as long as you are able to successfully connect to the web proxy server.

Though there are still some things to consider depending on the quality of web proxy you are using. The majority of web based proxies will have issues with complex javascript, flash objects, java, and other types on load event processing. Some web proxies will not properly proxy all content due to various reasons (usually due to the proxy parser being unable to "understand" certain element of a website being viewed through the service) which means any content that does get properly sent through the proxy will still be loaded directly from your browser which would still be susceptible to any sort of blocks or filters.

Comment: Thank you. I run my own proxy so I'm aware of the bugs with the service. Thanks for your detailed reply!

Comment: I run a proxy network too :)